# Netty 5.0.0: bytes from incomplete frame are discarded

Tags: binary, netty, message, decoder

I'm writing a decoder-handler for a binary message format which is possible to decode up to the last complete element of the message in the available bytes. So if there's an array of `int64` values, you read the highest multiple of 8 bytes which is less than `ByteBuf.readableBytes()`. I'm using netty 5.0.0.Alpha2.

My problem is that it looks as though Netty is discarding the unread bytes left in the `ByteBuf`, rather than appending new network-bytes to them; this means that when I try to resume decoding, it fails since there are missing bytes and a corrupt stream.

Are there `ChannelHandlerContext` or `ByteBuf` or `Channel` methods which I should be invoking to preserve those unread bytes? Or is the current/only solution to save them in a scratch space within the handler myself? I suspect that buffer-pooling is the reason why a different buffer is being used for the subsequent read.

Thanks

Michael

PS: I'm not keen on using the `ReplayingDecoder` or `ByteToMessageDecoder` classes as fitting my decoder library around them would be too intrusive (IMHO).

Comment: what is the length of the frame that you are expecting?

Comment: It varies, but can be up to 2GB.

Comment: I think I might have solved it by `.retain`ing the `ByteBuf` if there are still readable bytes in it and keeping a handle to it till the next read, then wrapping it and the "new" `ByteBuf` in a composite buffer. I'll write something up at some point, unless someone comes up with a better answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Are there ChannelHandlerContext or ByteBuf or Channel methods which I should be invoking to preserve those unread bytes? Or is the current/only solution to save them in a scratch space within the handler myself? I suspect that buffer-pooling is the reason why a different buffer is being used for the subsequent read.

That's what `ByteToMessageDecoder` does. If I understood correctly, you want your buffer always has n * 8 bytes.

```
public class Int64ListDecoder extends ByteToMessageDecoder {
    @Override
    protected void decode(ctx, in, out) {
        final int inLen = in.readableBytes();
        final int outLen = inLen / 8 * 8;
        out.add(in.readSlice(outLen).retain());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Trustin, thanks for your answer. I've seen the `ByteToMessageDecoder` but since a message can be up to 2GB, the decoder is specifically designed to be resumable and to support "windowed reads". The point is that I should be able to read a 2GB message in any given (sane) chunk size, using an read-buffer of, say, 256Kb. (1/2)

Comment: The original question is relates to what to do with unread bytes left in the buffer at the end of a partial read, which may not be a multiple of eight -- that was simply an example to illustrate how bytes may remain unread at all. There are different data-types, in particular string-types, which are varying length: eg "this is a char-vec value".length(). (2/2)

Comment: I see. You're gonna have to implement some state machine, then. Depending on the complexity of the protocol, it can be a little bit messy. Please take a look at `HttpObjectDecoder` for an example.  You can implement a decoder without using `ByteToMessageDecoder`, though.